# I cant print my json file inside of html

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, innerhtml

Hello im doing an ajax request **`to print  a json file on my html`**, but i have a problem when im trying to do it ,i don have any feedback or  error ...in fact when i click on inspect element they are inside of DOM (tags+ json file) here is my code , **I hope someone can help me**...`json file is external obviously but i put here....

```js
var robot = (function (window,undefined){
    var jsonObj = "";
    function ajaxRequest(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200){
                try {
                    jsonObj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    console.log(jsonObj.artista.length);
                }

                catch(error){
                    console.error("json parse error", error);
                }



                var sideBarContent= "";
                var desktopContent = "";


                var playlistContainer = document.getElementById("slide-out");
                var plalistContainerDesktop = document.getElementById("collection");

                for(var i = 0; i < jsonObj.artista.length; i++){
                    sideBarContent += '<li><audio src="'+jsonObj.artista[i].song+'"><span>'+ jsonObj.artista[i].cancion +'</span></audio></li>';
                    playlistContainer.innerHTML = sideBarContent;
                    console.log(sideBarContent);

                    desktopContent += '<audio src="'+jsonObj.artista[i].song+'"><span>'+ jsonObj.artista[i].cancion +'</span></audio>';
                    plalistContainerDesktop.innerHTML = desktopContent;
                }
            }
        }
        xhr.open("GET", "js/list.json", true);
        xhr.send();

    };


//    chooseItem function (){
//        for(var i = 0; i < jsonObj.artista.length; i++){
//            if (){}
//        }
//    };


    ajaxRequest();

    return {
        ajaxRequest : ajaxRequest,
//        chooseItem : chooseItem,
    };
})(window);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Mr Robot - Web Player</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/css/materialize.min.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">


</head>
 <header>

     <nav class="deep-orange">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="nav-wrapper">
          <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Mr Robot</a>
          <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
          <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><i class="material-icons">add</i></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="side-nav" id="slide-out">
            <!-- contenido dinamico -->
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Playlist</a></li>
<!--            <li><a href="sass.html">Bible Black</a></li>-->
<!--            <li><a href="badges.html">cancion 2</a></li>-->
<!--            <li><a href="collapsible.html">cancion 3</a></li>-->
<!--            <li><a href="mobile.html">cancion 4</a></li>-->
<!--            <li><a href="mobile.html">cancion 5</a></li>-->
          </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
   </nav>

 </header>
 <section class="content">
  <div class="container">

   <div class="row">
       <div class="col s12 m9">
           <div class="card">
               <div class="card-image">
                  <img class="responsive-img" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/2KH83vVDNc4/maxresdefault.jpg">
                  <span class="card-title"><h3>Demonizer</h3></span>
               </div>
               <div class="card-content">

                <div class="row controls">
                 <div class="col m3 s3">
                  <i class="material-icons">skip_previous</i>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col m3 s3">
                  <i class="material-icons play">play_arrow</i>
                 </div>


                 <div class="col m3 s3">
                  <i class="material-icons">skip_next</i>
                 </div>

                 <!-- <div class="col m3 s3">
                  <i class="material-icons">repeat</i>
                 </div> -->
                </div>




               </div>
               <div class="card-action">
                 <a href="#">artista-cancion</a>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>

       <div class="col md3">
        <div class="collection" id="collection">
            <a href="#!" class="collection-item deep-orange">Playlist</a>

      </div>
       </div>
   </div>





  </div>
 </section>
 <section id="carlos"></section>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mat.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you are not getting any feedback, that would mean `if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200){` is never true. use an `else` and log readyState/status to see what happens - either that or use modern xmlHttpRequest features to drag your code into the 21st century - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/

Comment: thanks for your help i appreciate it!!!!